# Usage of the word "don't" + "Substitute"

Tags: negation, do-support

"It's important to support business, but meal deal vouchers don't substitute for effective public health messaging and measures"

The above excerpt is from a political advert and was ridiculed for its poor grammar and structure today on Twitter. In particular, the use of "don't". Is anyone able to explain exactly why this is inappropriate?

My English isn't perfect and I've been trying to figure out why this is not correct.

EDIT - Here is the tweet

https://twitter.com/MattChorley/status/1280843436657172481

Comment: Without quoting one or two of the tweets, it is hard to tell what is being criticized. I do not see any grammatical errors. I do not like certain aspects of its style, but that is personal opinion. (For example, I prefer "are not substitutes," but that merely reflects my taste.) More importantly, what is quoted does not make any sense **without additional context**: why these represent a binary choice is not clear.

Comment: Here is the tweet. 

https://twitter.com/MattChorley/status/1280843436657172481

Comment: Stylistically inelegant perhaps, but not ungrammatical.

Comment: @Harry What are the criticisms? You do not link to any criticisms. (I do **NOT** twitter: it seems to make everyone who uses it revert to the intelligence of a six year old.) Please quote one or two.

Comment: From what I gather, the use of "Don't + substitute". 

1. Don’t substitute is, in my opinion, horrible English. Are no substitute?

2. “Aren’t a substitute” would be my preference

Comment: "... but meal deal vouchers *do not* substitute for effective public health messaging and measures." I wouldn't necessarily use this phrasing, but it is not grammatically incorrect since substitute is being used as a verb with "meal deal vouchers" as the subject.

Comment: It's not grammatically correct **if** the verb "substitute" doesn't work as an *ergative* verb -- or is it more fashionable to call such a *labile* verb now?  Regardless of label, on one hand, I don't expect all native speakers to find an ergative "substitute" acceptable, nor all to find it objectionable.  On the other, I don't expect political issues to garner only rational and cogent objection.  Do we have much very good information on either hand?